# Dooplay Disable Scrollbar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Currently I'm using Dooplay Theme for Wordpress.

How to disable video source scrolling bar? So It will show all sources?

[image: scrollbar]

Here's the source code

```html
<div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-minimal-dark mCSB_scrollTools_vertical" style="display: block;">
    <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
        <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 50px; display: block; height: 113px; max-height: 150px; top: 17px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
            <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 50px;">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mCSB_draggerRail">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://pastebin.com/dl/C2GNRcD6 (css code)

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't a lot of code to go on, but you can try to set 'max-height' to a bigger value.

Comment: Is that code just the rendered html from “view page source”?  The actual source code is most likely in a PHP file. It’s possible you can correct it with some custom CSS but have you tried asking on the [theme support forum?](https://doothemes.com/forums/)

Comment: Do you have the CSS of the theme, specifically the part where it applies the scrolling?

Comment: @Stackerexp not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

```
#playeroptions {
max-height: 100%;
}
.dooplay_player .options {
height: auto;
}
```